# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally with ChromeDriver Selenium on Ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-16.04

I am stuck with a Chromedriver problem, I have read some documents on the internet to circumvent the error I am getting.

This is what I have done. Already two Google Chrome windows are open. I have tried installing Selenium and Chromedriver using pip. When I try to open a browser using `d=webdriver.Chrome()` it throws following error. I have tried specifying the executable path as well by d=webdriver.Chrome('usr/bin/chromedriver') still no go.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
 packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 156, in __init__
 self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
 packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in 
 start_session
 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
 packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in 
check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 
Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 
(47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 4.13.0-41- 
generic x86_64)
```

Referred another document which tries to install selenium in a virtualenv but in venv also getting the same error. I have also provided the 777 permissions to the /usr/bin/chromedriver

```
 (env) root@XL-UbuntuOnAryMac$ pip freeze | grep selenium
 selenium==3.12.0
 (env) root@XL-UbuntuOnAryMac$ pip freeze | grep chromedriver
 chromedriver==2.24.1
 (env) root@XL-UbuntuOnAryMac$ chromedriver --version
 ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881)
 (env) root@XL-UbuntuOnAryMac$ whereis chromedriver
 chromedriver: /usr/bin/chromedriver
 (env) root@XL-UbuntuOnAryMac$ 
 (env) root@XL-UbuntuOnAryMac$ ll /usr/bin/chromedriver
 -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7903592 Jan  9 18:35 /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Comment: I have one more basic question. Whats the difference in chromium-chromedriver and selenium chromedriver? i have tried specifying the path of chromium-chromedriver but still no luck.

Comment: Any update is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have chromium-browser installed? Is it compatible with chromedriver ( https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads ) ?

Comment: Also, seems like you are trying from Linux VM on Mac (?). Do you have X Window to show GUI app?

Comment: No, its not the VM Setup.I have installed full fledge Ubuntu 16.04LTS on my Mac, so yes its an X window system.

Comment: @RomanSusi I have chromium browser installed . Infact using chromium browser to add the comments on stackoverflow. How do i check whether the chromedriver is compatible with chromium-browser?

Comment: Check the page I gave: It mentions compatible Chrome versions for each chromedriver version.